# Check if specific username is logged in

Tags: users, user-access

How can you check if specific username is logged in?

Comment: I'd like to use specific css on the admin panel for a specific user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`wp_get_current_user` then compare the object that's returned `user_login` proprety with the specific username you'd like to check against.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse74389_check_username');
function wpse74389_check_username()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if($user && isset($user->user_login) && 'username_to_check' == $user->user_login) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How can this be modified to check for all usernames that are not `username_to_check`

Comment: @TravisPflanz if you're just looking to check for a logged in user: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Otherwise just modify the function to take the username as a parameter instead of being hardcoded.

Comment: The question is not about the current user, he means a specific user

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Please can you advise how to change this to check if the username is in an array of usernames, rather than just one? They can still be hard coded as per your example. Thanks!

Comment: Use `in_array` instead of a simple equality check.